# jQuery History Plugin, Google Sitemap and SEO

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, seo

I have been looking for an answer in the web but never got any precise answer.

I have an **index.php** page with two particular **DIV's**: **#post-title** and **#post-content**, whose content is loaded thorugh jQuery function. This function is called everytime a link is clicked

```
<a onclick="showPage('page')"></a>
```

Function:

```
function showPage(page, fadeInSpeed, fadeOutSpeed) {
 fadeInSpeed = typeof fadeInSpeed !== 'undefined' ? fadeInSpeed : 500;
 fadeOutSpeed = typeof fadeOutSpeed !== 'undefined' ? fadeOutSpeed : 200;
 pageUpper = page.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + page.slice(1);

 var History = window.History;
 History.pushState(null,pageUpper, "index.php?page=" +page);

 $("#post-title").fadeOut(fadeOutSpeed, function() { // Callback del fadeOut..
     $("#post-title").html(page);
     Cufon.refresh(); // I reload Cufon plugin on the div
 }).fadeIn(fadeInSpeed);

 $("#post-content").fadeOut(fadeOutSpeed, function() {
     $("#post-content").load(page + ".php");
 }).fadeIn(fadeInSpeed);
}
```

This is the function and includes the History.pushState. Now, when I go directly to an URL like for example: **?page=curriculum**, I added in the index.php file the following code to recall the above function:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page'])) { // Controlla l'URL e restituisce la pagina corretta.
?>

<script>
$(function() {
    showPage('<? echo htmlentities($_GET['page']); ?>', 1000, 1);
});
</script>

<?
}
?>
```

Everything works FLAWLESSLY but now I have a little question: is this going to be against SEO? Will the Google crawlers index correctly my website? If not, what could I do to resolve this problem?

I thank you all in advance and Merry Christmas too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want you site to be indexable, you have to make sure all page contents are visible when JavaScript is disabled. It means for example that calling `page=curriculum`  with JavaScript disabled should display the curriculum data. Since the content seems to be retrieved through a `XMLHttpRequest`, it won't work. So, you have to implement the Google crawling scheme as described [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/).

Note that you will have to update your `sitemap.xml` file to declare your URLs to bots if they don't appear in the site (i.e. if you always use the `showPage()` function to display contents).

Answer (score -1):

As per your question ,we are not still understand,can you describe your Domain Name which can analyzed your actual problem, even if only index.php is problem then you can re-write your URLs via .htaccess file
Let's example,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/$ http:// %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ index.php?rewrite=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ index\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http:/ /www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Two Example for re-write URLs for no-www and removed index.php

Comment: Hi @Manishkumar. As you don’t understand the question, please don’t try to answer it.